# Several task executors in spring integration

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-aop, spring-integration

I am currently working on a project involving lots of asynchronous tasks running independently. I have one spring configuration file.

```
<task:executor id="taskScheduler" pool-size="5-20">
<task:executor id="specificTaskScheduler" pool-size="5-50" queue-capacity="100">

<!-- integration beans and 
     several object pools, with a total number of 100 beans created 
     using CommonsPoolTargetSource -->
```

I specifically created two executors - one to be used for spring integration needs and custom executor in order for it to run only my tasks feeding it to integration beans with explicit reference. After that I supplied a long running task to be procesed. My EAR runs on WebLogic and I dumped stacktrasce of threads being run and was very disappointed to find out that most of fifty threads in my custom executor wait in a executor's queue for an object to be available from the pool. I did not want CommonsPoolTargetSource to use my executor as a platform for managing its sources. What can I do here? Maybe creating a separate spring file with CommonsTargetSource beans will solve it? Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: I'm not sure it is factor, but one thing to remember is that when you allocate a thread-pool (I assume a `ThreadPoolExecutor` is backing the scheduler) that it will add jobs to the queue, before the non-core threads are utilized.  This is _completely_ counter-intuitive to me at least.

Comment: Gray's comment seems right on target. The order is basically: 1) use a core thread 2) if not enough core threads, add to the queue, 3) if the queue has reached capacity, grow the pool by adding a new thread (up to the max)... those added threads then can timeout and be removed again based on the idle time setting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. Turned out that pool was not a problem, I just had to add more instances to it and slightly increase the pool size with queue capacity set to zero and rejection policy set to an execution of the call in the caller's thread. I have yet to test it under heavy load though.